# WCF IIS Hosted Webservice SSPI Negotiation failed

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, iis

I have an IIS hosted WCF webservice using WSHttpBinding. This all worked locally, but I have reconfigured my test client to use the server and I am getting "The Security Support Provider Interface (SSPI) negotiation failed."

From what I have read I am hitting an issue to do with either cross domains, or kerberos authentication.

I have a test client on my local dev pc in my office. running svcutil gives me the correct configuration (its the same as my local configuration except for the url)

my client endoint address is;

```
 <endpoint address="http://services.foo.com/ACLTestService.svc/ACLTestService"
            binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_IACLTestService"
            contract="IACLTestService" name="WSHttpBinding_IACLTestService">
            <identity>
                <servicePrincipalName value="host/wduABC" />
            </identity>
        </endpoint>
```

I don't have a certificate so can't use https, and I require some basic authentication at least to try and protect the service, so I am reluctant to just use BasicHttpBinding

Before I waste too much time on this, if I get a new account created on the server that can run this service (and presumably runs the app pool.), then pass that as the servicePrinciple from my client, will that suffice. Or do I need to change the way I am approaching this problem?

Comment: Your SPN name doesnt look right. You can check naming conventions for SPN at https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc961723.aspx

Comment: Thanks, I'll check that later. Thats what I found using command line tools I saw mentioned in another post. I have got it working using basicHttpBinding for now, but need it to be mire secure before it goes to the production servers.